# SELECT where the first two numbers are equal

Tags: mysql

I have this in my database:

```
75012
75016
94400
94500
94300
78400
```

I would like to select only the string where only the first two numbers match  and show how many 94 there are so it will output 75012 = 2, 94 = 3, 78 = 1.

Here is what I tried:

```
select cpostal from fiche_personne WHERE cpostal LIKE LEFT(cpostal, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a group by clause in your query.

```
SELECT LEFT(cpostal,2), COUNT(*) AS total
FROM fiche_personne
GROUP BY LEFT(cpostal,2)
```

please note that the COUNT(*) isn't the best way to complete the query but I don't know your actual table structure, so you should change this to an actual column name

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(cpostal) from fiche_personne WHERE cpostal LEFT(cpostal, 2) = 94;
```

Resource: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp

Comment: cpostal contains lots more numbers than 94, how can I make it select every number that start with the same number

Comment: SELECT distinct left(cpostal,2), count(cpostal) FROM talenddepol.ytblNumtest group by left(cpostal,2)

(anyway i guess i have some difficulties to understand your question ^^ what you want the result to look like, can you give maybe a example? :) )

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(i INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(75012),
(75016),
(94400),
(94500),
(94300),
(78400);

SELECT MIN(i) i, COUNT(*) total FROM my_table GROUP BY LEFT(i,2);
+-------+-------+
| i     | total |
+-------+-------+
| 75012 |     2 |
| 78400 |     1 |
| 94300 |     3 |
+-------+-------+
```